# How to hide the GitLab distribute cache location in pipeline log?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab Kubernetes executor with S3 distribute cache, everything working perfect, just don't want to display the S3 bucket name in pipeline log, cause it will expose to every organization member. Any idea?

```
Checking cache for bc1ac8cd5b67911d3aec89bc08e14f097f2a4b60-1...
Downloading cache.zip from https://${bucketNameDoNotWantToDisplay}.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cache/runner/${runnerId}/project/{$projId}/${cachekey}
Successfully extracted cache
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no inbuilt option for this. However, there may be some workarounds.

1. You can create a **masked** [instance level variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-an-instance) or [group variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-group) whose **value** contains the part of the URL you want to hide. This will cause all occurrences of that value to be masked in job logs.
2. you could add a proxy container (e.g., NGINX, HAProxy, Squid, etc) to your pod and use that. Configure your cache to use the proxy address instead and configure the proxy to forward to S3. In which case only the proxy container address (only available within the pod) would be exposed.
3. Fork the gitlab-runner source code and create your own image with modified source code that prevents the message from being emitted to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, sounds good just need some extra effort.